# How to load a locally stored text file in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to load a text file as a part of a component. The file name is a passed in via a prop, and the component returns a paragraph tag with the text in the text file.

I wanted the text file to be in the src folder, but I can only get it to work in the public folder, so I'm taking that as a puzzle to solve later.

Right now I'd like some guidance in how to return the text from the `PromiseResponse`. I'll paste my current code below.

```
async function get_text_file(filepath){
    return fetch(filepath)
        .then((resp) => resp.text());
}

export function TextFile(props) {
    
    let filepath = `./${props.fileName}.txt`;
    let text = get_text_file(filepath);

    console.log(text);
    return (
        <>
            <p>{text}</p>
        </>
    );
}
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: what is `.then(function(data){return data})` supposed to do? if `fetch` succeeds (and remember, it might fail, so have a `.catch` at the end) then the response.text() will return the (promise of the) file's content. So just put your console.log _inside_ the second `then`. You're currently running it immediately after initiating the fetch instead of as part of "what happens once fetch succeeds".

Comment: Reference of use perhaps here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text

Comment: You're right @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, that wasn't doing what I thought it was meant to. I have edited it some because after some testing I found my original example was not working as intended as a whole, where it was before. I apologize for the inconvenience, I'll edit the code to reflect the current changes. I still am at a loss on how to return the PromiseResult however.

Comment: If you want the text files in your `src` folder, they'll need to be bundled. You might need a [specific asset module configuration](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) for `.txt` files though, not sure if they're supported out-of-the-box

Comment: @Phil that's not going to work if it's supposed to load files based on some prop that can be any random string, or if there are _lots_ of files. In that case it has to be a server endpoint. So... morthemex: are these files known before hand and is it a small set or are we talking megabytes of data in files that may not even exist at build time?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans if you use `import()` and provide enough static information, eg `import(\`./assets/text-files/${fileName}.txt\`)`, Webpack should be able to optimise the bundle

Comment: certainly, but you don't want to front load a bundle with data only some users will only ever need. Fetch is almost always still an excellent call for late loaded data =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `get_text_file()` is asynchronous and returns a `Promise`.

Use the [state hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to initialise your `text` property and provide a way to update it when the promise resolves...

```js
import { useState } from "react";

const get_text_file = async (filepath) => {
  // prefix public dir files with `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`
  // see https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/${filepath}`);

  // check for errors
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw res;
  }

  return res.text();
};

export function TextFile({ fileName }) {
  const [text, setText] = useState(""); // init with an empty string

  useEffect(() => {
    get_text_file(`${fileName}.txt`).then(setText).catch(console.error);
  }, [fileName]);
  return (
    <>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: This Worked! Thanks, I'm new to react and haven't worked that much with it, but this helped fill in some of the gaps I've been needing to find!